# Is there something like list comprehensions for collections.deque in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, deque

### Question

Is there a way to do something like

```py
some_list = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

but return a `collections.deque` object instead of a list?   In particular, I'm attempting to avoid creating a list and converting it with `deque(some_list)` since that adds a factor of O(n) to the time complexity as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23487307/6457597) and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52394481/6457597).

### Context

I'm working on a practice HackerRank problem for fun (but will avoid sharing it here to avoid the risk of people spoiling the fun of finding an answer).  Consequently, I won't be giving an example *output* since it would only make sense within the full context of the problem.  There are, however, some relevant things I can disclose that don't run the risk of spoilers.

##### Relevant stuff

1. I'm taking in very large lists/deques (up to 100k elements) via stdin.  They need to be converted to integers after (or while) being read in.
2. Elements in the list/deque itself are between 1 and 2<sup>31</sup>.
3. I need to quickly compare and pop from both ends.  **There's *no* need to** (a) look in the middle of the data, nor (b) sort it.
4. I'm restricted to using stdin to take in the data, but I will know the size of the list/deque ahead of time.
5. Fast runtime execution is desired, but I'm unfortunately restricted from using Numpy, Pandas, and Numba to help.

###### My reasoning for thinking about deques and list comprehensions

Because of (3) & (5), it seems like the `deque` object is the best way to go.  Because of (1) & (5), I'd like to convert the input into integers right away which is why list comprehensions came to mind.

###### Example input

The 1st line, `n`, tells me how many integers will be on the 2nd line.

```
4
5 2 42 199
```

###### Example code snippet to read in input

The following code works for reading in the input while converting it to integers:

```py
n = int(input())
wish_this_was_a_deque = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

But as mentioned before, I'd like to immediately convert the input into integers *while also* creating a `deque` and skipping the list entirely (for performance speed reasons).

###### Concluding remarks

Perhaps I'm mistaken in thinking that immediately converting the string input from stdin into integers and storing them in a `deque` would be faster doing this:

```py
from collections import deque
# Get input, split on spaces, covert to integers, append to some_big_list
some_big_list = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
# Convert some_big_list into a deque
some_big_deque = deque(some_big_list)
```

If so, please feel free to correct this misconception even if there is a way to do a "deque comprehension".

In any case, I'm still interested if a "deque comprehension" is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Python offers a few types of comprehensions, but the most general form is the generator comprehension. When you write

```
[int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

This produces a list immediately. But without brackets

```
int(x) for x in input().split()
```

this is a *generator comprehension*. It produces a lazy iterable that, when evaluated, will produce the values. It's as though we had written

```
def my_generator():
  for x in input().split():
    yield int(x)

my_generator()
```

but much, much shorter. Now, the reason this is useful is that [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), like many built-in Python collections, takes an arbitrary iterable as its constructor argument. And a generator is a type of iterable. So to get rid of the intermediate list, take your list comprehension

```
some_big_deque = deque([int(x) for x in input().split()])
```

and remove the brackets

```
some_big_deque = deque(int(x) for x in input().split()) # Look, Ma, no brackets!
```

Comment: ...but be aware that this will usually be *slower* than if you just used a list comprehension.